# Failed to run slider after kognitio cluster creation

Tags: kognitio

I am trying to integrate kognitio with kerberized cluster.

While creating kognitio cluster I am getting below error:

> Starting slider cluster for test1 Failed to run slider command
>   /home/kognitio/kodoop/slider/bin/slider start kognitio-test1

I have followed the steps provided on kognitio community forum. But still facing same issue. please help.

Comment: please specifically mention what you've tried so far

Comment: followed the steps mentioned in the link . I am new to kognitio https://kognitio.com/documentation/latest/install/install-edge.html

Comment: There's already a reasonable ongoing thread on this issue in the Kognitio Community Forums at https://kognitio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=515